# CSS Not Linking in Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

In Chrome, my website is working as I would like it to. But for some reason, in Firefox, the CSS is not being linked whatsoever and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

The only thing that's different in Firefox when I go into the inspector, the browser has added a `</link>` to the end of the CSS link, but I can't get rid of it because I didn;t actually code it.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this issue?

The website is: http://www.renegademagsu.com

And here's my header section HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Renegade Magazine</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

CSS

```
 /*
Theme Name: Renegade
Theme URI: N/A
Author: Noelle Devoe
Author URI: http://www.noellesnotes.com
Version: 1.0
*/


 body {
     background-color: #000;
     font-family:'Source Sans Pro', Arial;
     font-size: 18px;
 }

b, strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

 .container {
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 header {
     width: 100%;
     height: 135px;
 }

 .logo {
     width: 260px;
     height: 135px;
     float: left;
 }

 nav {
     width: 685px;
     height: 135px;
     padding-left:15px;
     float: left;
 }

 nav ul li {
     float: left;
     line-height: 135px;
     position: relative;
 }

 nav ul li a {
     font-size: 24px;
     color: white;
     background-color: black;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-right: 20px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     display: block;
 }

 nav ul li a:hover {
     text-decoration: underline;
 }

 nav ul ul {
     width: 200px;
     height: 50px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 85px;
     left: 0;
     display: none;
     z-index: 1000;
 }

 nav ul ul li {
     float: none;
     line-height: 50px;
 }

 nav ul ul li a {
     font-weight: regular;
     font-size: 20px;
 }

 nav ul li:hover ul {
     display: block;
 }

 .search {
     width: 260px;
     height: 135px;
     float: left;
 }

 section {
     width: 640px;
     float: left;
 }

 .post-container {
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
 }

 .post-image img {
     max-width: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
 }

 .post-content {
     position: relative;
     left: 30px;
     width: 580px;
     z-index: 2;
 }

 .thumbnail-positioning {
     bottom: 110px;
     margin-bottom: -110px;
 }

 .post-content p {
     line-height: 22px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

 .post-content img {
     max-width: 100%;
 }
 .post-meta h3 {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 12px;
     color: white;
     margin-bottom: 3px;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
 .post-meta a {
     color: white;
     text-decoration: underline;
     font-weight: bold;
 }

 .post {
     background-color: white;
     color: black;
     padding: 15px;
 }

 .post ol {
     list-style-type: none;
     list-style-type: decimal !ie;
     /*IE 7- hack*/
     margin: 0;
     margin-left: 3em;
     padding: 0;
     counter-reset: li-counter;
 }

 .post ol > li {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding-left: 0.5em;
     min-height: 3em;
     border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 }

 .post ol > li:before {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: -1em;
     width: 0.8em;
     font-size: 3em;
     line-height: 1;
     font-weight: bold;
     text-align: right;
     color: #464646;
     content: counter(li-counter);
     counter-increment: li-counter;
 }

 .post p:last-child {
     margin-bottom: 0 !important;
 }

 .post h1 {
     font-size: 34px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 7px;
 }

 .post a {
     color: black;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .page {
     width: 550px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 15px;
 }

 .page p {
     line-height: 22px;
     margin-bottom: 15px;
 }

 .page h1 {
     font-size: 34px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
     margin-bottom: 7px;
 }

 .leftimage {
     margin: 0 10px 2px -50px;
     float: left;
 }

 .leftcaption {
     margin: 3px 0 0 80px;
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 11px;
     width: 220px;
 }

 .leftimage img {
     max-width: 300px;
 }

 .rightimage {
     margin: 0 -50px 2px 10px;
     float: right;
 }

 .rightcaption {
     margin: 3px 80px 0 0;
     font-style: italic;
     font-size: 11px;
     width: 220px;
 }

 .rightimage img {
     max-width: 300px;
 }

 aside {
     width: 290px;
     float: right;
 }

 aside h1 {
     color: white;
     font-size: 28px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 aside .widget {
     margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 aside ul li {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 aside ul li a {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 aside ul li a:hover {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

input[type=text]{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color:#505358;
    font-size: 18px;
}

 footer {
     width: 100%;
 }

 footer .widget {
     width: 300px;
     float: left;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
     padding-right: 20px;
 }

 footer h1 {
     color: white;
     font-size: 28px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 footer ul li a {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 footer ul li a:hover {
     font-size: 19px;
     color: black;
     background-color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
 }

 .alignleft {
     float: left;
     margin: 0 10px 2px -45px;
 }

 .alignright {
     float: right;
     margin: 0 -45px 2px 10px;
 }

 .fix {
     clear: both;
 }
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: http://renegademagsu.com/wp-content/themes/renegade/style.css
is this the css you want to link with ??

Comment: @j08691 I've posted my HTML.

Comment: @Ron Yes! And it's working fine in Chrome, just not in Firefox.

Comment: @Noelle please post your CSS as well. There might be a FF only issue in there.

Comment: What does the HTML look like *after* PHP has parsed it? You can view this by right-clicking the page in a browser and choosing "View Source" (or equivalent).

Comment: @Noelle let delete

 /*
Theme Name: Renegade
Theme URI: N/A
Author: Noelle Devoe
Author URI: http://www.noellesnotes.com
Version: 1.0
*/

this and blank spaces above and check I don't know it will solve it out or nat but let try that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a typo: `"type/css"` instead of `"text/css"`. Chrome is ignoring the problem, Firefox is not.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" />
```

Will fix you up.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as soon as Stackoverflow lets me!